# How to redirect back to app after Spotify sign in?

Tags: flutter, oauth, spotify

I am working on building a flutter app that uses Spotify auth.

I reach until the permissions screen and after the user clicks Agree, it should technically close the window and redirect to app. But instead I get the error as shown in the image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MUb1.png

I feel like its the redirect URI but I don't get what I am doing wrong.

I use the `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?` API with the required arguments as shown below.

```
const clientId = 'client_id';
const redirectUri = 'com.app.soundrise://login-callback';
var codeVerifier = generateRandomString(128);
var codeChallenge = generateCodeChallenge(codeVerifier);
var state = generateRandomString(16);
var scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email';
```

I have also configured my URI scheme in iOS as shown below.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
      <array>
          <dict>
             <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
             <string>Editor</string>
         <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
         <array>
            <string>com.app.soundrise://login-callback</string>
         </array>
      </dict>
   </array>
```

I have also added this URI as my redirect URI in the Spotify dashboard.

Comment: Did you try to implement Deep Linking in your Flutter app?